# Обновление данных в ListView(QML)

Tags: c++, qt, qml

```
ListView {
            id: view
            model: skillModel
            delegate: SkillDelegate {
                width: ListView.view.width
                name: model.name + ' -'
                time.text: model.hours + ':' + model.minutes + ':' + model.seconds
                today.text: ' +' + model.todayHours + ':' + model.todayMinutes + ':' + model.todaySeconds
                pomodoroCount: model.pomodoros
            }
        }
```

`ListView` читает данные через производный от `QAbstractListModel` класс. Как обновить данные в `ListView` после их изменения? Изменяю данные в qml через Q_INVOKABLE функцию на c++ стороне.

Comment: Если Вы правильно реализовали `QAbstractListModel`, то всё будет работать правильно. Читайте документацию по этому классу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было реализовать сигнал dataChanged() родительского класса модели.